# AutoMapper ignores ForMember calls on parameterized constructor construction of an target entity

Tags: c#, automapper

Because my Issue on Github was closed im opening an thread here.

In my option this is clearly a bug of AutoMappers behavior. Because this directly leads to unexpected errors.

Therefore i directly filed an issue on Github (and not an question here).
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4357

#### Source/destination types

```cs
public class ModelA
{
   public string Text1 { get; set; }    
   public string Text2 { get; set; }    
}

public class ModelB
{
  public string Text1 { get; set; } 
    
   public ModelB() { }
   public ModelB(string text1)
   {
      Text1 = text1;    
   }
}
```

#### Mapping configuration

```cs
public class ModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
   public ModelMappingProfile()
   {
      CreateMap<ModelA, ModelB>()

         //This is a workaround to fix my issue
         //.ConstructUsing(_ => new ModelB())
        
         .ForMember(x => x.Text1, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Text2));
   }
}
```

#### Version: 12.0.1

#### Actual behavior

AutoMapper uses the best fitting constructor and ignores my custom ForMember handling completely.
Because im not the owner of the target entity i cannot edit the model itself. My only workaround is to manually declare a ConstructUsing that is using the default constructor. After that Automapper is using my ForMember calls correctly

#### Steps to reproduce

Look at this fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/G3hs4l

Or this gist:
https://gist.github.com/dp-sgr/1e8abf159102a400bfc4e5158df8999d

Please Mention:
My scenario is a little bit more complex. I only added a simple to unterstand sample to describe this bug.
Of course i don't want to map from Text1 to Text2 or similar

#### Expected behavior

I expect that ModelA.Text2 gets mapped to ModelB.Text1. As declared in my mapping profile.

This could be achieved by one of these solutions:

- AutoMapper uses the best matching constructor (presumably as of today) BUT uses my configuration "ForMember" for the constructor parameter
- AutoMapper only using the "empty contructor" and does its mapping handling normally
- AutoMapper at least throws an exception because the .ForMember call is complety ignored because its mapped from the constructor

Personally i think both first approaches would fit the "best-case" handling of automapper behavior. But i only want the problem itself to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is an actual bug is a little bit argumentative, because what you are seeing is a result of constructor mapping - that's a feature of AutoMapper that is by default enabled.

You can disable it:

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.DisableConstructorMapping());
```

or modify the selector logic resposible for deciding whether to use constructor to better fit your needs. In the example below, I'm limiting it only to public, parameterless constructors:

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ShouldUseConstructor = constructor => constructor.IsPublic && !constructor.GetParameters().Any();
});
```

Read more about constructors in [AutoMapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Construction.html).